# yammer integration :- writing activity using open_graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph, yammer

While writing activity  it return exception
ex  {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}

I'm using the following code :-

```
  public static string PostRequesttoYammer(string postBody, string url,string authHeader = null, string contentType = null)
    {
        string results = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            HTTPWebReq = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            HTTPWebReq.Method = "POST";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
                HTTPWebReq.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + authHeader);
            byte[] postByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
                HTTPWebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            else
                HTTPWebReq.ContentType = contentType;
            HTTPWebReq.ContentLength = postByte.Length;
            Stream postStream = HTTPWebReq.GetRequestStream();
            postStream.Write(postByte, 0, postByte.Length);
            postStream.Close();
            HTTPWebRes = (HttpWebResponse)HTTPWebReq.GetResponse();
            postStream = HTTPWebRes.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader postReader = new StreamReader(postStream);
            results = postReader.ReadToEnd();
            postReader.Close();
            postStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return results;
    }
```

I have obtained access token after that i'm trying to write an activity on yammer network .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mihkn.png)

The image shows the content of local variables of function.

Answer (score 0):

check the bellow code:

```
           yam.platform.request({
                url: "activity.json", 
                method: "GET",
                data: {
                    "activity": {
                        "actor": { "name": "name", "email": "name@domain.onmicrosoft.com" },
                        "action": "create",
                        "object": {
                            "url": "https://www.news.google.com",
                            "image": "url",
                            "description": "Testing Description",
                            "title": "Open Graph Title"
                        },
                        "private": "false",
                        "message": "testing commit"
                    }
                },
                success: function (activity) { 
                    console.log("Activity request was successful.");
                },
                error: function (activity) {
                    console.error("There was an error with the request.");
                }
            });
```